# Why does rviz seg faults when laserscan is added?

Tags: rviz, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Terminal output:
rviz
[ INFO] [1398274970.767543066]: rviz version 1.9.34
[ INFO] [1398274970.767625438]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1398274971.013525609]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

As soon as I add a laserscan in rviz. No matter what settings I chose, as soon as I enter the topic: /amigo/base_front_laser
then rviz seg faults.

In fuerte, it still works properly. How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156766/why-does-rviz-seg-faults-when-laserscan-is-added?/) by [maxbaeten](https://answers.ros.org/users/15146/maxbaeten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-04-24**:
Which ROS version? Which Rviz version (you can check by $rosrun rviz rviz)?

**Comment by [maxbaeten](https://answers.ros.org/users/15146/maxbaeten/) on 2014-04-25**:
rviz version 1.9.34

ROS GROOVY

UBUNTU 12.04

amigo@maxbaeten:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1398427199.380737791]: rviz version 1.9.34
[ INFO] [1398427199.380829386]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1398427204.813868693]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is common bug with Rviz 1.9.34 in Groovy for non-Nvidia video cards. If you do a sudo apt-get update does it update to  Rviz 1.9.35 for you? I would recommend that, switching to Hydro, or compiling one of the other versions of Rviz from source (maybe 1.9.33 or 1.9.35).

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1